# Declared but never read when it is

Tags: typescript

I'm creating a library using typescript with `.d.ts` generation enabled.

The problem is, `.d.ts` generation requires me to import types from packages I depend on for type generation.

*But* I don't actually use it inside my file. So if I do include it, I get an `is declared but never used`.

example without type import :

```
import { connect, } from 'react-redux';

export const foo = connect(
    () => ({}),
    {},
);
```

gives a

> Exported variable 'foo' has or is using name 'InferableComponentEnhancerWithProps' from external module "/node_modules/@types/react-redux/index" but cannot be named.

But then changing the import to :

```
import { connect, InferableComponentEnhancerWithProps } from 'react-redux';
```

remove the error previous error and create instead:

> 'InferableComponentEnhancerWithProps' is declared but its value is never read.

---

my tsconfig.json :

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strict": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["es6", "es7", "esnext", "dom"],
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "declaration": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true
    }
}
```

---

I could disable the `noUnused` check or use a `@ts-ignore`. But I'd like to avoid both.

Comment: Are you using TypeScript 2.9 and still seeing 'cannot be named' error? It should be fixed according to the [release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#relaxing-declaration-emit-visiblity-rules)

Comment: Indeed this got fixed with 2.9.0. Funilly I was already using 2.9.2. But it my vscode was using 2.8, which confused me.